# Apache Ignite nuget package installed with full framework

Tags: c#, .net-core, nuget, ignite

I created a very basic application in C# 7.3, VS2017 for dotnet core. I referenced the Apache Ignite nuget which seems to be based on NetStandard 2.0. But here is what I get:

[image]

**Package 'Apache.Ignite 2.7.6' was restored using '.NETFramework,Version=v4.6.1' instead of the project target framework '.NETCoreApp,Version=v2.2'. This package may not be fully compatible with your project.**

So my question is, even though it seems to be based on .NETStandard why it is installed using full framework.

Answer (score 0):

Warning `NU1701` is a known issue. You can safely ignore it, Ignite is fully functional under .NET Core 2.x:
https://apacheignite-net.readme.io/docs/cross-platform-support

This has been fixed in upcoming Ignite 2.8 (to be released by the end of the year), .NET Core 3.0 is also going to be fully supported.